# CSS: changing linear gradient background to width of all flex elements? Different span per letter

Tags: css, flexbox, gradient, clip

Sorry if the title was confusing, I'm not sure how to phrase it. I am currently using the method of setting the **background-image** to a **linear-gradient** and then using **background-clip** to make the words (in this case, random names) display with the gradient as a fill color.

The names are generated from JS with each letter in its own span because they get individually animated later and also it is a different name each time.

My problem is that I need to use **background-attachment** on "fixed" for the gradient to cover the whole word instead of each letter individually because it's applied to the class on each span:

[image: example of spreading gradient]

This is almost perfect, but the size of the gradient is always 100% the size of the wrapper, and the text is centred, so only long words get the red and yellow at either end and all medium/smallish words get just the blue and green in the middle:

[image: comparing long names vs short names]

I have tried changing **background-size** to 100% or 400px etc but regardless of how wide I make it, there is still the problem that it is fixed. Ideally, I could find a way to give it a variable size it so it is always the width of the whole name and so every name, regardless of length, includes the entire gradient, but I have not been able to find a way to do so as the parent container is also the child of a larger container and does not change with its flex children.

```
.rainbow-wrapper {
    width: 57%;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.rainbow-letter {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(243, 72, 104,1) 20.375%,rgba(241, 70, 105,1) 20.375%,rgba(158, 0, 236,1) 37.375%,rgba(73, 93, 245,1) 54.75%,rgba(73, 245, 145,1) 68.75%,rgba(245, 231, 73,1) 80.375%);
    background-size: contain;
    background-clip: text;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: why are you making each letter inside a span?

Comment: Can you change the markup to add a `div` around each `.rainbow-wrapper`?

Comment: They're in a span because each letter gets individually animated. The rainbow-wrapper div is inside another div for layout

Comment: Why do you need the wrapper to be a flex-container? Can the rainbow be on the flex-parent, or must the children have it? How are you going to animate the letters, and how does that influence in how we can style the rainbow effect?

Comment: You can try something like this if you can wrap the `.rainbow-wrapper` with another div. I don't think you can do it any other way while keeping the letters in individual spans. https://jsfiddle.net/amo2c9gx/